# How to connect to speacial links using TIdHttp in delphi?

Tags: http, delphi

**Browser Example**

I have the following link to connect to my IP Camera using user and password in the url.

```
http://admin:password@192.168.1.13/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/picture
```

If I open this link in Internet Explorer it show me the following message and can not open the link.

```
Windows can not locate <link>. Check your spelling and try again
```

When I open the same link in Chrome of Firefox it works fine and displays the desired jpg picture.

**Delphi**

In delphi I am using `TIdHttp` to get the picture from this link.

```
var
  Ms: TMemoryStream;
  PictureUrl: string;
begin
  try
    PictureUrl := 'http://admin:password@192.168.1.13/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/picture';
    IdHTTP1.get(PictureUrl, MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    MS.SaveToFile('C:\Users\karat\Documents\hikivision1.jpg');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;
```

The code works with another jpg image links, the problem is that this code gets a 178byts MemoryStream, this means that the picture is not being loaded.

I put a `TWebBrowser` in the form and I discovered that it is giving me the same error as in Internet Explorer browser, the browser does not support loading this type of url.

[image: Error in webbrowser]

**Translation:** Not possible to access this page. Check if your link is correct.

**Solution?**

I assume that if I find a way that `TIdHttp` behave as Chrome and Firefox, it will load correctly the desired picture. Any way to do that or another possible solution?

Comment: You say that you are receiving 178 bytes, what do those bytes actually look like? Please show the actual bytes. I'm guessing maybe an error HTML page rather than a JPG image, right? If so, what does the HTML say? It may hold a clue to why the URL is failing.

Comment: Yes, that is right. That is why I upload the html error picture. This white screen is the HTML error.

Comment: That screenshot is not of an HTML page that the web server delivers to your client. That is an error page that is built-in to IE itself that it displays when it can't access the URL.  What does the web server actually deliver? What bytes is your `TMemoryStream` actually receiving when using `TIdHTTP.Get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit). Delphi's [`TWebBrowser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) component in VCL is just a wrapper for IE.

The code you have shown is not creating the `TMemoryStream` object before calling `TIdHTTP.Get()` with it. Is that just a typo here, or is your real code actually forgetting to do that?

Though Indy does parse username/password from URLs, and does support the `@` character in passwords, since you already know ahead of time what the values are then you should put them in the `UserName`/`Password` properties of `TIdHTTP.Request` explicitly rather than in the URL, eg:

```pascal
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := 'admin';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'poi@0413477';
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.1.13/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/picture', MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    MS.SaveToFile('C:\Users\karat\Documents\hikivision1.jpg');
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If that still does not work, it is possible that the web server in question is UserAgent-sensitive, delivering different content for different web browsers.  Some web servers do not like Indy's default value for the `User-Agent` request header (`'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'`, which can be changed globally via the `GIdDefaultUserAgent` variable in the `IdHTTPHeaderInfo` unit), so try changing the `UserAgent` to mimic a real web browser of your choosing, like Chrome or FireFox, eg:

```pascal
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := 'admin';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'poi@0413477';
    IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := ...; // ie: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.1.13/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/picture', MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    MS.SaveToFile('C:\Users\karat\Documents\hikivision1.jpg');
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not running then try to aditionaly set the following:

Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth, hoForceEncodeParams];

Comment: You can use an instance of TIdHTTP, let's say "IdHTTP1".

var retStr := IdHTTP1.get('The url you want to retrieve');

With the above statement, you can get the HTML text content from the site.
Hoping this is helpful.